# HOw do I get browser to get my latest version of a page

Tags: javascript

I have applications that run within the browser. When I make changes to pages and javascript I start getting calls from users who get weird results. I tell them to clear their cache and all is well.

Is there a way that I can force, or suggest to, the browser to get a new version of the page?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I found the perfect solution. I discovered that if you put a ? and some unique character after the file name, it forces the browser to get a new version when that version changes.

So instead of:

```
<link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/ngen.js"></script>
```

code:

```
<link href="css/mycss.css?1.0.28" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/ngen.js?1.0.28"></script>
```

and since I use php, I create a global with the release in my main config.php and tack that on to the file reference.

```
$GLOBALS['V_UNIQUE'] = "?1.0.28" // my current release number

<link href="css/mycss.css?1.0.28<?php echo $GLOBALS['V_UNIQUE']?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header on the server-side to prevent the browser from caching your files.

Comment: As long as the browser honors it.  Which is why it is suggested to use multiple no-cache methods, as in my first link.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

See this page for info on stopping caching of pages:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/10628.htm

See suggestions for .js/.css on this answer:

[How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

The idea is to timestamp filenames when they change, so the filename changes and the browser is forced to load a new copy.

Comment: What about cached HTML? Yesterday I changed the HTML of a dialog and a few people get a blank dialog, while most work?